# How to send a curl request using the command line in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, curl

I need send a curl request to get a push notification from apple, I am try do it using node.js and the command line, but when I send it I do not have any notification on my device, only is I use an external json.txt, but need send this json object in the command line itself.

my first example it don't work

```
 let args = `-v -d '{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"SENT_BY_NAME\",\"subtitle\":\"MESSAGE\",\"body\":\"MESSAGE\"},\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}' -H Content-Type:application/json -H apns-topic:com.myapp.ios -H apns-expiration:1 -H apns-priority:10 --http2 --cert apple_push_notification_certificate.pem:pass https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/tokenofdevice`;
```

this example work but I need some similar to my first example

```
 let args = `-v -d @json.txt -H Content-Type:application/json -H apns-topic:com.myapp.ios -H apns-expiration:1 -H apns-priority:10 --http2 --cert apple_push_notification_certificate.pem:pass https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/tokenofdevice`;
```

this new to me need some help thanks

Comment: Look into this git repo https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58

Comment: something is still not working well in my command line

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the JSON string in double quotes:

```
... -d "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"SENT_BY_NAME\",\"subtitle\":\"MESSAGE\",\"body\":\"MESSAGE\"},\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}"
```

Comment: still not working some one know a npm package can handle this and accept json object as a data ?

Comment: @AlfredoIzquierdo try `node-fetch` or `axios`